# Why is this user-defined conversion failing?

Tags: c++, c++11

This code fails but I think the conversion function chosen should be `operator std::string()` since it takes less steps (`Foo -> std::string`) than the `operator const char*()` (`Foo -> const char* -> std::string`).

```
struct Foo
{
    operator const char*();
    operator std::string();
};

void f(Foo foo)
{
    std::string s2(foo); // Error!
}
```

The standard says the conversions are limited to one conversion sequence, and that conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous, so why are these failing?

The error is:

```
error: call to constructor of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') is ambiguous
    std::string s2(foo);
                ^  ~~~
note: candidate constructor
      basic_string(basic_string&& __str)
      ^
note: candidate constructor
      basic_string(const basic_string& __str);
      ^
note: candidate constructor
      basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc());
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use only non-explicit constructors and user-defined conversions, you should be [copy-initializing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) `s2` from `foo`, instead of [direct initializing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) it. Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and implicit conversion sequences.

Try this:

```
std::string s2 = foo;
```

Your existing code is invoking the constructor of `std::string`, with an object of type `Foo`. Since there are valid conversions from `foo` to argument types of multiple `std::string` constructors, with the same conversion sequence length, you run into ambiguity issues.

Answer (score 1):

Well, both conversions need *one* step:

- `foo` -> `char const*` to use `std::string::string(char const*)`
- `foo` -> `std::string` to use `std::string::string(std::string&&)`

The third overload is an option overload result needs to consider but the constructor taking a `std::string&&` is a better match than the one taking a `std::string(std::string const&)` and would be chosen if they are the only options.

Currently I can't easily test it but I would expect that

```
std::string s3 = foo;
```

would prefer the conversion via `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. The line which generates the error contains the constructor of an `std::string` instance, which has valid constructors using both `const char*` and the `std::string&` copy constructor. Both require a single implicit conversion step using your supplied conversion overloads, and it's therefore ambiguous which one is intended.

Explicitly cast the object to invoke the intended conversion - depending on your internal logic the `const char*` constructor is probably 'cheaper', as the `std::string` conversion probably just returns `std::string((const char*)this)` anyway. If this is the case I would even recommend removing the `std::string` convertor as it will always cause ambiguities which are never more performant.

Comment: On the other hand, the `std::string` conversion operator returns an rvalue which could be used for move-construction or -assignment, so performance shouldn't be an issue, and the `std::string` conversion operator avoids any possible complications with the lifetime of the returned pointer value, so personally, I'd suggest removing the `const char *` conversion operator instead.